# IoC containers, fluent interfaces circular references

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have an app which contains views which inherit from IView (project A)

I have Windsor IoC Container as a Singleton in another project (project B)

Project A has a reference to project B, and makes a static call to the container to resolve the concrete type for particular views

If I use XML configuration to configure my container then all is well and good.

If I try to use the fluent interface for configuring my contrainer I get a circular reference, as I now need project B to reference project A in order to specify the interfaces and concrete types

So what is the best way to go about this using the fluent interface?

EDIT:

Project A has this on app startup :

```
IoC.Instance.Start(); // this configures the container from config
IoC.Instance.Container.Resolve<IBootStrapper>().Start();
```

Where IoC is a static class defined in Project B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best is to design your application around dependency injection (constructor injection) and configure the container at the startup path (composition root) of your application. Ideally, your project B should not have a dependency on the DI container itself, or at most have some bootstrapping code in the project that allows creating the configuration for that project.

When you register the container in the startup project (possibly project A in your case) you won't have a circular reference.

**UPDATE**

In the comments you explained that your Project B project is solely for IOC bootstrapping. There is nothing wrong in having a bootstrapper project, because this will allow you all the other projects completely clean from the use of any IOC container. You would typically use a bootstrapper project if you have multiple libraries that are reused by multiple applications (for instance a business layer that is used by a web app, a web service and a windows service).

The bootstrapper project should however, only bootstrap 'static' dependencies of the reusable projects. There is no sense in configuring things that change per application project. Next, since the bootstrapper is in itself a reusable project, you don't want it to have a dependency on one of your application projects, since that would be the part you will be swapping. What's the use of having a reference to a ASP.NET web app when running a Windows Service? That would be yucky.

A bootstrapper project is especially useful when having multiple application projects, but this doesn't mean that you can't use it in a single application solution. Still the same rules apply here, since you would end up with circular references, as you already noticed.

In other words, the solution is simple: Let the bootstrapper only bootstrap dependencies for the projects below and not the application project. If however, the application project is the only project you have, you don't need a bootstrapper project; it won't work.

Comment: +1 although I'd delete that 'ideally'. Project B must not have a reference to the container.

Comment: Do you mean Project B? That is the one I said contains my Windsor Container. That is where I create and configure the container...confused

Comment: So are you suggesting just deleting project B and having everything in the same project?

Comment: @Roonooir: Remove the `IoC` class from Project B, because you should not call `IoC.Instance.Container.Resolve` directly from within Project B. See here for more information: http://bit.ly/a7lU76.

Comment: @Roonooir: "are you suggesting just deleting project B". Absolutely not. Separating your applications into layers is still good practice in my book. No: make sure Project B does NOT use the `IoC` class nor Unity directly.

Comment: But Project B is where the IoC class is defined. It is a Singleton wrapper around IWindsorContainer. This is really confusing me. Are you sure you keep meaning to refer to Project B. Could you perhaps expand on your answer to make thing clearer?

Comment: ps I am not doing Service Location. I am calling the Resolve method once to construct the whole of my object graph. I am not making lots of calls to Resolve all over the place. Just once per initialisation

Comment: I dont call IoC.Instance.Container.Resolve from Project B. That is called on startup of Project A (in app.xaml) (as written in the edited quesion). I just said that the IoC class is defined in Project B (not called from there)

Comment: Why is `IoC` defined in Project B, since you don't call it from within Project B?

Comment: I wanted to move the IoC stuff outside of the UI project, as it seemed a reasonable seperation of concerns. I take it this is not the case? Are you saying the container should be created and configured inside the UI project? (UI project, which is also the startup project = Project A)

Comment: @Roonooir: You should configure the container in your UI / startup project. When your library project (B) is reused in multiple end applications, you can move the part of the configuration that is specific to that project (and doesn’t change) to that project (using `IWindsorInstaller`s for instance), but apart from having such registration facility, that library should not have access to the actual configured container and should not do any resolving itself. Only the UI project should have access to this. @Mark Seeman: Do you have anything to add to this?

Comment: well if the configuration of the container is done in the UI/Startup project, then that leaves nothing left in the IoC project (project B). That is literally the only thing going on in project B : A singleton wrapper round the IWindsorContainer and the "start" method on the instance which does the configuration. I do have a win service in the solution that I also want to use the IoC class with,(hence moving the IoC to a seperate solution),but you seem to be saying do the configuration of the container should be done in the project that starts the app. So in each of the UI and Win Service apps?

Comment: @Roonooir: Project B is solely for doing IoC? I didn't get this from the question and it might change things. Project B is your Bootstrapper project. I would still suggest not having a static IoC class in there. Just define an `IWindsorInstaller` implementation in there and call `container.Install(new ProjectBInstaller())` from within the UI project.

Comment: Yes, project B is solely for IoC. (Hence my confusion at some of the answers). I take it this is a bad idea? My bootstraper (which is in Project A) needs to know about iViews and Views that are in the UI project (A). On startup, in app.xaml (proj A) I ask the container (proj B) to resolve an instance of IBootstrapper. Hence the original question - this works OK when using xml config, but produces a circular dependancy when using the fluent interface

Comment: So I have created a WindsorInstaller for my UI project which lives in project A. And also a WindsorInstaller for my Windows Service which is in the same project as the service. And in Project B my IoC class takes a WindsorInstaller as a parameter to the start method. So when the UI project starts up it calls the IoC class with a UIInstaller, likewise when the Win Service starts, it calls the IoC class with a ServiceInstaller. Does that seem reasonable to you?

Comment: @Steven - thanks - see my comment above. I think I may have unduly complicated this question by calling my startup class (in project A) bootstrapper. My IoC class is the one that actually bootstraps the container. This lives in project B. And i'm now passing a WindsorInstaller to it from my UI project (and I do the same for my Win Service project)

Comment: @Roonooir: I would turn the thing around. Instead of sending the UIInstaller to Project B, define a public `ProjectBInstaller` and instantiate and install in the startup path of both the web app and the service. This ensures that you don't have a reference to the contain in Project B and allows you to get rid of the `ProjectB.IoC` class.